# torch_optimizer has no attribute 'SGD'

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import `torch_optimizer` on Google Colab. I have successfully `!pip installed torch_optimizer` and then imported it. However, every attribute I call with torch_optimizer gives an attribute error:

AttributeError: module 'torch_optimizer' has no attribute 'SGD'

This holds true for SGD, Adam, etc.

Here is a photo of my code. Thanks!

[Pytorch Optimizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyVv3.jpg)

Comment: I get the same error in the pytorch tutorial. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#exclusion-from-the-dag

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the documentation of [pytorch-optimizer](https://pytorch-optimizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The vanilla SGD is not there. There are small modifications of SGD as AccSGD, SGDW, SGDP etc. You can use the simple pytorch optimizer `torch.optim.SGD`. Check [this](https://github.com/jettify/pytorch-optimizer/blob/910b414565427f0a66e20040475e7e4385e066a5/examples/viz_optimizers.py#L166) visualization script where they are comparing the baseline SGD to other methods implemented by this library. Same thing holds for `Adam` as well. Pretty clear from the script.